# Cortana being moody

Tags: cortana

Why won't Cortana understand the "read message" command (upon receiving SMS message) when I'm driving and understand everything else I say? Instead, Cortana will ask "who do you want to text"

Comment: Which version of Cortana you are using?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and found that talking slower and clearer solved it. It was still a problem with stammer/stutters but this cannot be helped yet

Comment: I've tried it all (even with a bunch of flowers) but she won't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to speak `READ IT`, it actually works for me!

> [image: Cortana]: Message from +00000000! **Read it**, Or Ignore it
>
> Me: Read it.
>
> Cortana: `THAT WORKS!`

Answer (score 0):

It's just a problem with the current speech recognition technology. You might have to try to speak more clearly.
If you just want to have your incoming messages read aloud, you could turn on that feature from:
Settings > Speech